# Sqlite format date from hour to hour

Tags: sqlite, date, format, hour

I want store in my sqlite database date in format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM-HH:MM there is any solution of this ? I found only that YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no specal data type for dates.

You can store dates in any format you want, but if you want to use any of the [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), you have to use one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

What you want to store is not a date (a point in time), but a time interval.
There is no built-in support for intervals; the best you can do is to store the start and the end of the interval in two separate columns.

Please note that *storing* a date and *displaying* a date are two different things.
It would be easier to compute the length of an interval when the two date values are stored in one of the numeric date formats.